# Cakephp 3.x hasOne inserts default foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a table X connected to table Y through containing 
When I want to inner join (matching) this with table Z using hasOne and a function.
CakePHP automatically connects to the nonexisting default row through hasOne

```
  public function initialize(array $config)
{  
    $this->belongsTo('Y', [
        'bindingKey' => 'initialen',
        'foreignKey' => 'initialen'
    ]);

    $this->hasOne('Z');
}
```

further

```
   public function search($c)
{

    $query = $this->find('all')->contain('Y')->matching('Z', function ($q) use ($c) {

        return $q->where(['Z.client_ID' => $c]);
    });


    return $query;


}
```

**I am getting error**

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'Z.search_id' in 'on clause'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution myself

```
$this->hasOne('Z',[
'foreignKey' => false
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If Z.search_id does not exist, you have to specify other foreign key that does exist:

```
$this->hasOne('Z',[
    'foreignKey' => 'some_key'
]);
```

More info: [CakePHP hasOne association](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#hasone-associations)

Comment: Correct, but than this will added also to the query. What I do not want.
Let's say I specify the foreignKey as 'team_ID' 

FROM 
  `archief` `searches` 
  INNER JOIN `archief_Z` `Z` ON (
    `Z`.`client_ID` = 81 
    AND `searches`.`ID` = (`Z`.`team_ID`)
  ) 
  LEFT JOIN `archief_Y` `Y` ON `Y`.`initialen` = (`searches`.`initialen`)